# how to use if conditions for post request data in php

Tags: php, html, if-statement, switch-statement

I have three input boxes in html:

```
<input type='text' name='source' />
<input type='text' name='target' />
<input type='text' name='date' />
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='go' />
```

In this, i am successfully retrieved source and target data from mysql but if date is not supplied then i have to retrieve last 7 days data from database. I can try this, and created a function for select query but use seven variables and structured them in table form. Problem is i can't design a suitable logic for all of this like,

- retrieve seven days data of source if date is not suppplied retrieve
- seven days data of target if date is not suppplied

I can try this using if and elseif condition like:

```
if (isset($_POST['source']) && empty($_POST['target'] && empty($_POST['date'] ) {

  //fired query function seven times with different dates through pass a query
  $init->get_result( $_POST['source'], date('Y-m-d') );

}
```

function for select_query:

```
function get_result() {
   $query = "select count(*) from tablename where column=$_POST['source']";
   $this->select_query($query); //from there select query function called
}

function select_query($post, $date) {

$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$row->$res->fetch_row();

return $row[0];

}
```

And if date is supplied then data is retrieved for specific date, all this done well but not logic well. Also i am using form action as php_self to get an result on same page, but when i am using result in variable and show in html table then i have to given a condition that after specify post data result is show, which is not done. This is so lengthy, but problem is very critical for me. Please have a look on this.

**Update:** I get values from database in php in this code:

```
if ( !empty( $_POST['source'] ) && empty( $_POST['target'] ) && empty( $_POST['date'] ) ) {

        echo '<table border=1>';

        echo '<tr>' . '<td>' ."<input type=submit name='tod' value=" . date( 'Y-m-d' )." >" . '</td>' . '<td>' . $adinit->get_req_data( $_POST['source'], date( 'Y-m-d' ) ) . '</td>' . '</tr>';
}
```

I am created a input button in echo statement, which shows date. I am trying to create an event on button which shows another tabular data from database. How can i do this?

Comment: which meaning has `select_query` function?

Comment: i am using this function to generate result for a query which is specified in another functions. Indirectly i am calling select_query function. First i'll call query function inside i am calling select_query function.

Comment: Just a couple of 'comments', literally. a) Please make sure your query does not include raw post data - you are cleaning it first, right? Secondly, it's probably a good idea to use a function call for checking parameters like you have in your if(), such as if($this->isValidDateSource()) {} or something similar to keep your code more readable and modular.

Comment: @MyStream: I totally agreed with your terms, in fact i do, but initially i have to make an elegant logic for this post data. Because i need seven days data so i have to run query seven times, function can take it but i have to use seven variables for this and show in tabular structure.

Comment: @MyStream: Hey, i am using conditions like: if ( !empty( $_POST['source'] ) && empty( $_POST['target'] ) && empty( $_POST['date'] ) ) {} or i have to call these validations through functions? through functions i have to defined 7 times variable to call these functions. Is this correct?

Comment: @shihon: I'd have used something like if($this->isValidDataSource()){} where function isValidDataSource(){} may contain: return (isValidSource() && noTargetOrDate()); Inside each function do the POST checks and comment why you need them in the isValidDataSource() function.  That way you can run your 'readable' code without worrying about a lot of if/else statements. It's a trade off between readability and portability vs run time execution speed, but in this case - it is negligible and I'd opt for readability.  You may also get mileage from using 'IN' in SQL instead of an exact data match?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtotime()` function:

```
if (isset($_POST['source']) && empty($_POST['target'] && empty($_POST['date'] ) {
    $time = strtotime('-7 days'); // or strtotime('-1 week') works too
    //fired query function seven times with different dates through pass a query
    $init->select_query( $_POST['source'], date('Y-m-d', $time) );
}
```

Appendix:
In order to work with time interval of one day you have to change your query to something like this:

```
get_req_data($source, $date) { 
    $dateMax = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date) + (60 * 60 * 24)); // + 1 days
    $query = "Select count(*) from tablename where time >= '$date' AND time <= '$dateMax'";
    ...
}
```

This will only work if `time` column is of datetime/timestamp type.

Comment: Husnjak: use strtotime('-7 days') shows separate dates result or combined one, i have to show last seven days result in table.

Comment: Then supply me with more data, preferably entire SQL query where you use that date

Comment: get_req_data($_POST['source'], $date) { $query = "Select count(*) from tablename where time like '$date%'"; and then this query goes to select_query($query) function. Then for previous day, i am using there date('Y-m-d', time() - 24*60*60) and for prev another day using 2, 3, 4 etc.

Comment: just wondering, is the `time` column in your table of `datetime` or `timestamp` type? If is, then using `LIKE` operator is not good option since only on certain MySQL versions it wont produce warning (I assume you are using mysql). If you have that column as type of VARCHAR or other textual type, then again it is not a good practice to save date/time like that

Comment: you should probably modify your get_req_data() and get_result() methods to recieve one more parameter, check appendix to my answer

Comment: hey, i am using time column as timestamp type, so time generated automatically. And, i am specified all conditions in if else statement, and call functions in every if statement according to requirement but its very long. And i defined php above html, call by php_self action but result getting above html form. How to get result below html form

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20068/discussion-between-shihon-and-ivan-husnjak)